# Generating functions for sum of powers of two

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, generating-functions

I have the recurrence:

> $a_1 = 2$
>
> $a_{n+1} = 2^n + a_n$

How can I use generating functions to compute a closed form for $a_n$?

---

Here is what I did on my own:

Let $A(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} a_n x^n$

Multiply by $x^n$ and sum over valid values of $n$:

> $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_{n+1} x^n = \sum_{n \geq 1} (2^n + a_n) x^n$

On the left we have:

> $\sum_{n \geq 1} a_{n + 1} x^n = a_2 x + a_3 x^2 + a_4 x^4 + \ldots = A(x)/x - a_1$

On the right we have:

> $\sum_{n \geq 1} (2^n + a_n) x^n = \sum_{n \geq 1} 2^n x^n + A(x)$

So with some algebra (and the fact that $a_1 = 2$):

$A(x) = \frac{x}{1- x} (\sum_{n \geq 1} 2^n x^n + 2)$

This is where I get stuck. Did I make a mistake? Am I going about this the wrong way?

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to hints from @wj32 and @Dennis Gulko:

> $\sum_{n \geq 1} 2^n x^n = \sum_{n \geq 1} (2x)^n = \frac{2x}{1 - 2x} $

Using this identity and some algebra, I get:

$A(x) = \frac{x}{1-x} \cdot \frac{2 - 2x}{1 - 2x} = \frac{2x}{1 - 2x}$

Comment: What is $\sum_{n\ge 1}(2x)^n$?

Comment: Thanks @wj32. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Is this homework, or are you just exploring?

Comment: @wj32 -- I'm trying to learn independently. I'm currently following along in the Analytic Combinatorics class on Coursera, but this is a sequence that I ran into on my own. (Incidentally, this sequence is the expected number of coin flips you need before you get $n$ heads in a row.)

Comment: @dsg: I edited my answer

Comment: You go wrong, the sum without the first term is $\frac{A(x) - a_1}{x}$. Other than such algebra mistakes it looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$, then 
$$\begin{align*}\frac{A(x)}{x}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}x^n=a_1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1}x^n=a_1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(2^n+a_n\right)x^n\\
&=a_1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(2x\right)^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n=a_1+\left(\frac{1}{1-2x}-1\right)+A(x)
\end{align*}$$
**Edit:**
Using some algebra you should get:
$$A(x)=\frac{2-2x}{1-2x}\cdot\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{2x}{1-2x}$$
Can you take it from here now?

Comment: I have $A(x) = \frac{1}{2x - 1} - \frac{4}{x - 1} - 3$. So I can write it as $A(x) = -3 + \sum (4 - 2^n) x^n$. This is actually the first problem in generating functions I'm doing on my own. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Now your'e done - by comparing coefficients with $A(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$, you have a closed form for $a_n$ (assuming there are no computation mistakes - but here you clearly have at least one, since you get $a_n=4-2^n$, which is negative for $n>2$, while $a_n$ is positive).

Comment: I must have made some mistake. I believe the answer should be $a_n = 2^{n+1} - 2$.

Comment: @dsg: Another edit

Comment: I flipped a negative sign in the denominator. It is fixed now. Thanks so much for your help!